# spawn-sync post install fails during React native starter kit installation on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, react-native, spawn

I am trying to install a React native starter kit (Ignite) on Ubuntu 14.04.4 and keep on getting spawn-sync post install fails.

Earlier there was Eaccess issue and I fixed it by following instruction in this video,

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

node version - v6.3.0
npm version - 3.10.3
ignite - https://github.com/infinitered/ignite

When I try to globally install ignite, I am getting the following error,

```
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer     requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/root/.npm-global/bin/ignite -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-ignite/index.js

spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-ignite/node_modules/spawn-sync
node postinstall
module.js:442
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-   native-ignite/node_modules/spawn-sync/postinstall'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
/root/.npm-global/lib
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-41-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-  native-ignite"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall: node postinstall
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall script 'node postinstall'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the spawn-sync package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node postinstall
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs spawn-sync
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls spawn-sync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/sith/react/myapplication/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the npm permission instruction video for the normal user and that solved my problem. Earlier I was trying this with root user and that didn't work well for me.